# Weird solution to "String index out of range" in Python 3 - can't figure out why?

Tags: python, for-loop, range, indexoutofrangeexception

So I'm doing the MIT 6.00.1 class, and have come across a problem-set, where I have to identify the longest alphabetical substring in a randomly generated string (eg. "abcdtttyyttt", the longest alphabetical substring would be "abcdt").

My code that solves the problem looks like this:

```
s = "abzabc"

longestWord = []
subStr = []

for i in range(len(s)):

    if s[i] >= s[i-1]:           
        subStr += s[i]     

    else:
        subStr = s[i]

    if len(subStr) > len(longestWord):
        longestWord = subStr

print("Longest substring in alphabetical order is: ", "".join(longestWord))
```

**!!! But this is what I don't understand !!!**

Before figuring this out, I spent hours on a solution where I would compare the current character in the 's' string (the randomly generated string I have to check) with the next character, which would look like:

```
if s[i] < s[i+1]
```

Using this solution, I always ended up getting a "String index out of range", as the last comparison between letters in the string i was looking through, would go out of range, because there would not be any letter to check against (the s[i]+1 part).

So how do I not get the "String index out of range" error when I compare s[i] with s[i]-1? Surely, there is no letter in front of the first letter, which means I'm somewhat "out of range"?

Hope someone can explain this to me! I haven't been able to find an answer anywhere else.

Comment: @DavidG won't that fail if the longest substring is at the start

Comment: @unutbu The OP doesn't have a problem (well, actually they do, but it hasn't caused a nice "out of range error") ... and they don't understand *why* they don't have a problem.

Comment: There is a typo:  You mean `s[i-1[` in the last-but-one paragraph.  Incidentally "how can this possibly work?" is always a good question to ask.  It either means the code is overcomplicated, or it needs a long explanatory comment, or it doesn't work - it just appears to.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `s[i-1]` when `i` is zero is `s[-1]`.  This doesn't return the character before the start of the string, it returns the *last* character of the string.  This probably isn't what you want!

The fix is probably to go back to using s[i+1], but to use:

```
for i in range(len(str)-1):
```

which will stop just before the last character in the string.

Alternatively, you can use:

```
 for i in range(2, len(str)):
```

which will start `i` at 1 (provided there are at least two characters - you probably need to special case a one character string).

Comment: i.e. `s[len(s) + 1]` is invalid, but `s[0 - 1]` is valid. Note that this means your code has a bug in it OP

Comment: @FHTMitchell - expanded.

Answer (score 1):

Your code will work, but firstly you will need to assign `subStr` s[0] value.

```
s = "abzabd"

longestWord = ''
subStr = s[0]

for i in range(1, len(s)):

    if s[i] >= s[i-1]:
        subStr += s[i]     

    else:
        subStr = s[i]

    if len(subStr) > len(longestWord):
        longestWord = subStr

print(longestWord)
```

You could use [`max()`](https://kite.com/python/docs/builtins.map) function with `key` kwarg set to [`len`](https://kite.com/python/docs/builtins.len) function and generator function:

```
def get_ascending_words(s):
    if not s:
        return
    if len(s) == 1:
        yield s
        return
    ws, i = 0, 1
    while True:
        if ws >= len(s):
            break
        while i < len(s) and s[i] > s[i-1]:
            i += 1
        yield s[ws:i]
        ws = i
        i += 1

s = "abzabcd"

print(list(get_ascending_words(s)))
print(max(*get_ascending_words(s), key=len))
```